# String-join pandas dataframe colums and skip nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to join column values into new column but I want to skip nan values:

```
df['col'] = 'df['col1'].map(str) + ',' + df['col2'].map(str) + ',' + df['col3'].map(str)'
```

For example if a col2 value is nan, corresponding col value becomes:

```
 val1,,val3
      ^
```

... but I want to suppress the unwanted comma corresponding to the NaN column:

```
val1,val3
```

Sample df:

```
col1 col2 col3
---------------
val11 nan val13
nan val22 val23
nan   nan val33
```

Desired output:

```
col1 col2 col3   col
---------------------
val11 nan val13  val11,val13  
nan val22 val23  val22,val23
nan   nan val33  val33
```

Comment: kindly share a sample dataframe, with expected output

Comment: To state your requirement clearly, you wan to string-concatenate the non-NaN columns, and you don't just want to suppress the NaN, but also the extra comma. for that column

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': {0: 'val11', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan},
        'col2': {0: np.nan, 1: 'val22', 2: np.nan},
        'col3': {0: 'val13', 1: 'val23', 2: 'val33'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
>>>
    col1    col2    col3
0   val11   NaN     val13
1   NaN     val22   val23
2   NaN     NaN     val33
```

```
df['col'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
print(df)
>>>
    col1    col2    col3    col
0   val11   NaN     val13   val11,val13
1   NaN     val22   val23   val22,val23
2   NaN     NaN     val33   val33
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
df['col'] = df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x[~x.isnull()].values), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2   col3          col
0  val11    NaN  val13  val11,val13
1    NaN  val22  val23  val22,val23
2    NaN    NaN  val33        val33
```

Comment: This is the best pandas idiom. but you don't need to do `x[~x.isnull()].values)`, you can just directly do `','.join(cols.dropna())`

Answer (score 1):

Improving on BeRT2me's one-liner, directly use `.dropna()` on aeach row's columns:

```
df.agg(lambda cols: ','.join(cols.dropna()), axis=1)

val11,val13
val22,val23
val33
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the dataframe from csv file then use:

```
df.read_csv(path , na_filter=False)
```

If you already have the dataframe then you can replace `nan` with empty string in this way:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

**Updated solution**:

From what I understand in your question you want to include only column values that aren't `nan`.

You can add a condition before aggregating each column value to the desired result column `col` on each row of dataframe:

```
df['col'] = ""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not pd.isnull(row['col1']):
        df.at[index,'col'] = f"{row['col1']} "
    if not pd.isnull(row['col2']):
        df.at[index, 'col'] += f"{row['col2']} "
    if not pd.isnull(row['col3']):
        df.at[index, 'col'] += f"{row['col3']}"
    df.at[index, 'col'] = df.at[index, 'col'].rstrip().replace(" ",",")
```

Console output:

```
    col1   col2   col3          col
0  val11    NaN  val13  val11,val13
1    NaN  val22  val23  val22,val23
2    NaN    NaN  val33        val33

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Replacing `nan` with empty string doesn't work! Don't understand how do you make use of this `~df['col1'].isnull()`?

Comment: `~df['col1'].isnull()` this will select only column value that isn't nan. Check my updated solution.

Comment: `df['col1'].isnull()` will return a truth value of a Series isn't that ambigious?

Comment: This will return True only if the column value is nan. for sure it will work for you.

Comment: So in this case you will only aggregate column values that aren't nan to the result col.

Comment: This is what I mean:
`----> if not df['col1'].isnull():
...
...
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @mattbluet check my latest solution. it should work for you.